# Map is missing when I "export as image" via print composer

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, printing

I have point data on a vector layer that prints accurately via print composer (when I 
"export as image"), however my map below either does not show up or shows up at an incorrect scale.   I used openlayers plugin yahoo street map for the map.

I have examples to illustrate what is happening, but can't post them here since this is my first time.  I'd be happy to email them to someone if you have ideas as to what might be going on.

I'm new to the world of QGIS, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using latest versions? It seems to be this fixed bug http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4223

Comment: I updated my openlayers plugin and that alone has seemed to help.  Thanks!