# Why is there a shift between OpenLayers and vector layer in print?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04 .
Does anybody know why the `.tif` or `.jpeg` or `.pdf` files I generate with the QGIS composer have different layers completely shifted?

For example, 2 layers: 1 open street map landscape and 1 layer of my GPS points.
In the composer window, the points are exactly at the right place, the map is nice and ready to be saved or printed...

But when I do `export to pdf` or `.jpeg` or `.tif` the picture that I obtain shows the map very small in a corner and the GPS point in the middle of a white picture. When I try to print, a white sheet of paper is produced.

Any ideas?

Comment: see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/map-is-missing-when-i-export-as-image-via-print-composer

Comment: which version of openlayers plugin do you have installed?